# docker file to run automation test in JS files

Tags: selenium, docker, automated-tests, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker file to run selenium tests for a java script based  project. Below is my docker file so far:

```
#base image
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome

#access to the project within docker container - Bundle app source
COPY  ./seleniumTest/project  /app

# Install Node.js
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install --yes curl
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -

#binding
EXPOSE 8080

#Define runtime  
ENTRYPOINT /app/login.test.js
```

while running with `$ docker run -p 4000:80 lamgadekamal/dockertest`

**returns**: Unable to find image 'lamkam/dockertest:latest' locally docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for lamkam/dockertest:latest not found. Could not figure out why am I getting this?

Comment: how do you run your tests locally? have you tried that command?

Comment: What command are you using to build and tag your Dockerfile?

Comment: I think you did not build the docker image? Also, how does this relates to `docker-compose`?

Comment: i was able to run locally by `node ./path/test.js` . However, now I am getting a `ReferenceError: beforeEach is not defined`, though i am not sure why since haven't made any changes on the file.

Comment: I did built the docker file and tagged it doing `docker build -t lamkam/dockertest  .`  and it has been successfully built too. 
Now, firstly I am trying to run it locally since i am getting a reference error as mentioned above in my cmd.js file which contains beforeEach function. `beforeEach(() => {
    screenshotIndex = 0;
}); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you need to build your image first, since the image cannot be found.

Run this command from the same directory where your `Dockerfile` is located. This will build the image.

`docker build -t lamgadekamal/dockertest .`

You can then verify that the image exists by running `docker images`

**EDIT:** After looking at this again, it appears that you are trying to run the wrong image. You are trying to run `lamgadekamal/dockertest`, but you built the image with the tag `lamkam/dockertest`? Seems like you have a typo. I would suggest running `docker images` to see exactly what is there, but in all likelihood, you need to run `lamkam/dockertest`.

`docker run -p 4000:80 lamkam/dockertest`

Comment: yes, i have built  it earlier doing so. Now, i would like to run the docker image, bind it to a port and automate the test in chrome browser.

Comment: You have a typo. You are trying to run `lamgadekamal/dockertest`, but you built the image with the tag `lamkam/dockertest`. You should try running `lamkam/dockertest` instead. Update my answer

Comment: i was away and sorry for late update. yes that was correct